# How to check if sympy relational holds for certain values

Tags: python, sympy

I have defined some constraints using relational GreaterThan -

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
constraint1 = (x >= 0)
```

I want to now check if the constraint holds for an arbitrary value of 'x'. I tried using `sympy.checksol`, but get an attribute error, so I'm guessing that's not the way to go -

```
In [7]: sympy.checksol(constraint1, {x: 3})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-cc41bd5986e3> in <module>()
----> 1 sympy.checksol(constraint1, {x: 3})

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy/solvers/solvers.pyc in checksol(f, symbol, sol, **flags)
    200         if attempt == 0:
    201             val = f.subs(sol)
--> 202             if val.atoms() & illegal:
    203                 return False
    204         elif attempt == 1:

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'atoms'
```

I even tried `constraint1.evalf` but it always returns itself -

```
In [10]: constraint1.evalf(subs={x: 3})
Out[10]: x >= 0

In [11]: constraint1.evalf(subs={x: -3})
Out[11]: x >= 0
```

So how do I evaluate the relational constraint for given values of its symbols?

Comment: Just found that `constraint1.subs({x: 3})` works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`evalf` is for numerical evaluation of expressions, which is not what you want here. Just use `subs`, as you discovered

```
>>> constraint1.subs(x, -3)
False
```

And be aware that if you plug something in that it can't figure out, it will remain unevaluated:

```
>>> contraint1.subs(x, y)
y >= 0
```

Also, subs only does basic checking. If you want more advanced checking, you should use `ask` (`ask` currently doesn't translate inequalities, so you'll need to convert them to `Q.positive` or `Q.nonnegative` manually).